# Firefox mangles bootstrap row display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just been tasked with redoing some of the layout on a project.  I'm new to this, so I apologize in advance if this is a simple issue.

Briefly, there's a row of date input and button elements above a highcharts chart.  This looks great in Chrome, but falls apart in firefox.    Both browsers are up to date, and it seems to be a problem regardless of windo size.

here's the code:

```
<div class="input-group date pull-left row" 
                     style="width:100%; padding-right: 0px;">

                    <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control resize:none"
                        placeholder="Start Date"
                        title="Start Date"
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        ng-model="chartCtrl.start_dateSelected"
                        is-open="start_dt_opened"
                        max-date="today"
                        datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                        ng-required="true" 
                        ng-change='dateChanged()'
                        close-text="Close"
                        >
                    <span class="input-group-btn date">
                        <button type="button" 
                            class="btn btn-default" 
                            title="Start Date Picker"
                            ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                            ng-click="start_date($event)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" 
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="End Date"
                        title="End Date"
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
                        ng-model="chartCtrl.end_dateSelected" 
                        datepicker-popup=""
                        is-open="end_dt_opened"
                        max-date="today"
                        {# todo: set min/MAX date properly                                      #}
                        datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
                        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                        ng-required="true" 
                        ng-change='dateChanged()'
                        close-text="Close"
                        >
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" 
                            class="btn btn-default" 
                            title="End Date Picker"
                            ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                            ng-click="end_date($event)">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>

                    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plotminus()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to pervious period">-</button> 
                    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plot1day()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to last 24 hours/1 day">1 day</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plot7days()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to last 7 days">7 days</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plot30days()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to last 30 days">30 days</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plot60days()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to last 60 days">60 days</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right col-md-2"
                        ng-click="plotplus()" 
                        ng-disabled="plotButtonActive"
                        title="Set range to next period"
                        >+</button> 

                </div>
```

Here's how it looks in Chrome:
[Properly laid out date inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUoo5.png)

And here's how it looks in Firefox:
[Firefox layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HdHN.png)

I'm just hoping that this is a familiar problem to someone out there.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS? Also, why are you using pull-left on a row? Also - you're aware that you're using SPAN for some elements, and then not others?

Comment: None that I created, but there are a number of stylesheets that have been included for various reasons.  I'm unaccustomed to working with this stuff.  Is there a way to discern which style elements, from which sheets, apply to an element?  I think the pull-left is a leftover from when the text inputs and calendar buttons occupied a row underneath the other buttons (60 days, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Take the elements out of the `span` tags and set the inputs width as needed. See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19437/

Comment: Thanks.  That was a good idea for an experiment.  Here's what happened:

  http://i.stack.imgur.com/OhWuI.png  Chrome looks the same, but now with small gaps between the inputs and the calendar buttons.

Comment: There's definitely some discrepancy in your code somewhere, I checked both Chrome and Firefox with the JSFiddle I provided, and it looked the same.

Comment: For sure.  This feels to me like something you'd need to have seen before.  Maybe someone will stumble across it and recognize the problem.

Comment: It will be something that's being called in one of the other stylesheets. Set specific rules for this form if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, it turns out this problem was due to a ::before pseudo-element that had display:table applied to it.  With that removed, Firefox presents the row properly.